# CodeIgniter Array to String conversion when inserting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code and I'm out of my wit already. I spotted the specific line where the error occurred by die(). This should have worked because I've similar codes as this one that worked.

**controller**

```
foreach($course_rows as $key => $val ) {
    $course_fields = array(
        'CourseCode' => $val,
        'CourseDesc' => $course_desc[$key],
        'programID' => $id
    );

    die($course_result = $this->model_admin->insert_course($course_fields));
}
```

**model**

```
function insert_course($data) {
    $this->db->insert('course', $data);

}
```

Comment: what you want to do and what type of error you found?

Comment: please do your homework and see for yourself what [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) does.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use different function instead of `die()`, I presume you would like to use `print()` or `echo()`, so foreach loop can do at least one cycle.

In other words get rid of `die()`.

```
foreach($course_rows as $key => $value ) {
    $course_fields = array(
            'course_code' => $val,
            'course_desc' => $course_desc[$key],
            'program_id'  => $id,
    );

    $this->model_admin->insert_course($course_fields);
}
```

Your model function does return no information (`null`) there is no use of printing anything, in case you want your model to return boolean or last inserted id, comment on your logic.

Comment: I still get the Array to String error without die() that's why I tried to pinpoint where exactly and found it there.

Comment: Well you didn't state anywhere that die() is a debug code (at least I did not understood). Anyway; please do following `var_dump($course_rows); die();` before foreach loop and edit your original question with result.

Comment: But I stated in my question that I spotted the specific line where the error occurred, hence the die()... maybe you understood that differently. Var_dump showed exactly my inputted values.

Comment: Well of course it did show your input, I wouldn't  ask if data structure was not important. Please do edit your question with var_dump data.